# delete every row after specific string in excel through C#

Tags: c#, excel

I want to delete every row that comes after my specific keyword and including the keyword row as well. Can anybody please help me with C# code.

Example :- I have not attached a dummy excel file as I am posting it from mobile.

I have a word in excel :- "hello user" so I have to delete all the lines of data after this including it as well. And most important this data is not on the fixed line it can be on any line number....Suppose for now I have given it on 10th line so it may come on 12th line in next file.

**Line no.  Data**
10.          "hello user"
11.            A
12.            B
And so on
.
.
.
.
.

Comment: Use Excel.Interop classes, run over every cell and search for your word, delete all rows after this line + the line itself.

Comment: thanks sebi but i'm looking for an automation process through C# as there will be multiple files to do it and I can use either C# or VB

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you need help iterating files in a directory? Opening Excel file in either Excel or a library that supports those files? Comparing strings? Please read [ask], [edit] your question to ask an answerable question and share your research.

Comment: I'm not a coder, so I don't understand a library things n all....

Comment: suppose- I have an excel file i need to delete all the lines of it after a specific keyword (including the keyword line) and I need to write that code in C#..... "I'm looking for a solution for a single file for now but a C# code"

Answer (score 1):

I think this code should work for you:

```
const string magicWord = "HelloUser";

Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Open(@"myWorkbook.xlsx");
Excel.Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Sheets[1]; //Excel has no zero based index!!!

int magicWordRowIndex = Int32.MaxValue;

 //Here we find your magic word. But we can't delete the rows here, so just save the index
 for (int row = 1; row <= worksheet.Rows.Count; row++)
 {
    for (int column = 1; column <= worksheet.Columns.Count; column++)
    {
       if (worksheet.Rows[row][column] == magicWord)
       {
           magicWordRowIndex = row;
           break;
       }
     }
  }

  //Now we run reversed, because else our magicWordRowIndex become invalid if we delete rows
  for (int row = worksheet.Rows.Count; row >= magicWordRowIndex; row--)
  {
     ((Excel.Range) worksheet.Rows[row, Missing.Value]).Delete(Excel.XlDeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftUp);
  }
```

Actualy I'm not able to test it but should do the job, maybe you need minor changes and fit it to your needs.

First it finds your magicword which is hardcoded on the beginning. After finding this word we go delete all rows from bottom up to your existing word.

> Notice that you need to reference: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Comment: Thanks Sebi, do we need to use any library

Comment: Thanks Sebi, do we need to use any library as I am getting error with few keywords

Comment: @user3895001 Yes sorry you need to reference Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Comment: This will not scale very well if the sheet is large. Communicating across COM is very slow. You would be better reading the whole sheet into a 2d array and then iterate over that.

Comment: @DarrenYoung I aggree with you that this is just the simplest solution and not the best one. On large files this can be very slow, so that everybody must fit it for his needs.